# How to make a bot react to its own message in discord.net?

Tags: c#, discord.net

The bot sends a message "Do u like or dislike smth" and reacts :thumb-up: and :thumb-down:, then calculates how many people voted for each option. How can I do it?
This is my code for now:

```
    public Task Respects(SocketGuildUser user)
    {
        var emoji = new Emoji("");
        Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"What do u think about {user.Mention}'s message?");
        return Context.Message.AddReactionAsync(emoji);
    }
```

And I don't completely understand how to add emoji reaction by text indificator (:thumb_up:).

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow doesn't write the code for you. You should try giving [Minimal Effort](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at least.

Comment: @Symon Sorry, edited ._. I just started working with discord.net and I don't really understand their documentation.

Comment: You might need the unicode for the emoji rather than the actual one itself (not for sure on it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself, there is my code:

```
    [Command("respects"), Alias("F")]  
    [RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.AddReactions)]
    public async Task Respects(SocketGuildUser user)
    {
        var emoji = new Emoji("\uD83C\uDDEB");
        string message = $"Press F to pay respects to {user.Mention}:";
        var sent = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(message);
        await sent.AddReactionAsync(emoji);
    }
```